.net MAUI application crashes in release mode when deserializing data from an http request
I have an app written in .net MAUI. The app uses passwordless authentication. The following experience is done via an emulator running Android.
The flow for this is as follows:

User enters their email address and sets login
A login request is made to the web api and an auth code is sent to the user
User enters the auth code in the app
A request is made to the web api to authenticate the details provided. I take the response and deal with it accordingly

On the final step I receive the following exception (I use Sentry to do error handling in my .net MAUI app)
System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: ExpectedStartOfValueNotFound, 0x1F LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
  ?, in void ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(ref Utf8JsonReader, ExceptionResource, byte, ReadOnlySpan<byte>)
  ?, in bool Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(byte)
  ?, in bool Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(byte)
  ?, in bool Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
  ?, in bool Utf8JsonReader.Read()

When I run the app in debug mode this works every time without fail. When I run this in release mode the app crashes.
I know that the request returns data as I can emulate the same request in Postman.
Where have I gone wrong and what are my next steps?

On the original request I did not handle the response content, but instead use the http response code to deal with the next steps. This pointed to me that the issue was with the system.text.json library in use trying to take the content being returned and handling although why would it work within debug mode and not release? This still doesn't make sense even when I've fixed the problem.
Having gone through postman the response from the web API was using gzip compression and I wasn't handling that with my httpclient instance. I added a handler (code below), added it to the httpclient instance and everything started working again.
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

I hope this helps someone having the same challenge.
